# extracting data from an IsoDep student card

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc

I have a student card with the following Technologies:

```
[android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
```

My ultimate goal is to emulate this card from my phone.

I don't know what type of card it is and the only prior knowledge I have on the card is that when you put the card on a vending machine the machine will display my student ID number so I can infer that my ID is stored somehow in the card (and that's what I'm currently trying to access).

So far I have managed to read the card and send commands to it using the `isoDep.transceive` method but I can't manage to extract the data in the card and I keep getting various error codes...
I have been using this website: https://web.archive.org/web/20090630004017/http://cheef.ru/docs/HowTo/APDU.info
I tried most of the relevant commands on here but so far no luck, I will note that when I send the following SELECT command I do get 9000 as a response

```
                (byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
                (byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction
                (byte) 0x00, // P1  Parameter 1
                (byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
                (byte) 0x00, // Length
```

any idea on what command should I try to send in order to get the ID out of the card?

Comment: cards are tiny computers that have certain public methods but they typically don't expose their internal data (like a crypto key used to sign payments in your name) because that's the point of them. So cloning cards is usually not possible. Your id is maybe readable, the interesting bits probably not

Comment: Im pretty sure that the authentication is done based on the id so that's what I want to read in order to know how the reader reads my card so then I can imitate the cards behavior when getting the same commands

Comment: I recommend to Start with the Tag type, one tool could be TagInfo from NXP: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite. Find out what tag type your student card is of and load the data sheet, where usually the read commands are described.